# Different Movement of The Enemy

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm making a 2-D game in Sprite kit and it's a game about an Ice elemental jumping and running across ice blocks and dodging fireballs shot by the Fire elemental. I want the fire elemental to move up and down on the right side of the screen. The screen is horizontal. I am trying to get the Fire elemental to move up and down the y-axis to a certain point and then go up to a certain point and repeat. However, I am not very sure how to do this. Help Please!

Comment: [SKAction moveTo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417768-moveto?language=objc) sounds like it would do the trick. Sequence a few of those together inside a SKAction sequence and bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for the help. I figured out how to keep my enemy moving infinitely in the manner I wanted.

```
let move1 = SKAction.moveToY(CGPoint: size.width * //int)

let move2 = SKAction.moveToY(CGPoint: size.width * //int)

let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move1, move2])

let repeat = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)

//enemy.run(repeat)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, but my first guess would be applying impulses to the ice elemental.

See this post for reference - [Applying impulses in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290323/applying-impulses-in-spritekit)